Angular 18 custom input: FormControl has strange behavior
I'm struggling with some strange behavior while using my custom input component.
First of all, I built a simple abstract class that has the main "features" and methods of the component, then, the input-component which has very few code:
// Abstract class

export abstract class BaseFormInput<T> implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() label: string
    @Output() onChange: EventEmitter<T> = new EventEmitter<T>()

    private changeInternal: (obj: T) => void
    private changeSub: Subscription
    private disabled$ = new BehaviorSubject(false)
    private required$ = new BehaviorSubject(false)

    public input = new FormControl(null)

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.changeSub.unsubscribe()
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.changeSub = this.input.valueChanges.subscribe(v => {
            if (!this.disabled$.getValue()) {
                this.onChange.emit(v)
                this.changeInternal(v)
            }
        })
    }

    writeValue = (obj: T) => this.input.setValue(obj)

    registerOnChange = (fn: (obj: T) => void) => this.changeInternal = fn

    registerOnTouched = (_fn: (obj: any) => void) => {}

    setDisabledState = (isDisabled: boolean) => this.disabled$.next(isDisabled)

    validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
        this.required$.next(control.hasValidator(Validators.required))

        // THIS LINE HAS WEIRD BEHAVIOR
        console.log(control, control.errors)

        return null
    }

    public get isDisabled$(){
        return this.disabled$.asObservable()
    }

    public get isRequired$(){
        return this.required$.asObservable()
    }
}

The input component is simply designed like this:
@Component({
    selector: "ec-input-text",
    template: `<div class="form-control">
            <label *ngIf="label">
                {{ label }}
                <span *ngIf="isRequired$ | async">*</span>
            </label>
            <input *ngIf="type !== 'textarea'" [type]="type" [formControl]="input" [attr.disabled]="isDisabled$ | async" />
            <textarea *ngIf="type === 'textarea'" [formControl]="input" [attr.disabled]="isDisabled$ | async"></textarea>
            <ng-template></ng-template>
        </div>`,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputTextComponent), multi: true },
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputTextComponent), multi: true }
    ]
})
export class InputTextComponent extends BaseFormInput<string> {
    @Input() type: "text" | "password" | "email" | "textarea" = "text"
    @Input() maxLength: number
}

Finally, I created a register-component, which uses the input.
HTML:
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <ec-input-text label="First name" formControlName="firstName" />
    <ec-input-text label="Last name" formControlName="lastName" />
    <ec-input-text label="E-mail" formControlName="email" type="email" />
    <ec-input-text label="Password" formControlName="password" type="password" />
</form>

The TS of the register-component has a public property like this:
public form = new FormGroup({
        firstName: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]),
        lastName: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]),
        email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]),
        password: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    })

Now, the issue is the following: in the validate method of the abstract class (where I put a comment), I tried to log the control errors, and I get a strange behavior: when logging the formControl, I can see in the console that the property errors is null, but if I log control.errors it logs:
{ required: true }

Even though the control is valid and I typed the value (in fact, control.value has a value and results valid).
So if i do:
console.log(control)

And I expand it, errors is null (expected behavior, correct!)
But if I do:
console.log(control.errors)

It is valorized (not correct, the control is valid!)
How can I figure this out? Thanks in advance!

This usually happens because Angular's validation runs asynchronously, especially when you’re working with BehaviorSubjects and custom ControlValueAccessor setups. as a solution, Try wrapping console.log(control.errors) in a setTimeout and this lets Angular finish updating the validation state first and ensure the control is marked as touched or dirty.

Oh.. it worked. I thought about some asynchronous behavior, but I didn't expect that property to change when accessing it.. If you want to answer the post, so I can mark it as solution :)

Do not use attr.disabled or disabled in reactive forms, you can try a directive or just manually disabling it using reactive form methods. It can lead to difficult to solve bugs, so recommending disabling it programmatically.
Disabling Form Controls When Working With Reactive Forms in Angular

You are not checking for the validation errors at the right place, the validate method is designed for you to insert custom validation that does validation specific to your control's value, mostly won't involve checking the other errors (not showing correctly).
When you check the errors of the control at this location, it is showing the previous state, so I guess the other validations are not updated. So please perform validation inside the validate function and do not check the other errors.
Also you can import the ControlContainer, get the formControlName and get the actual form control, you can use it to check the Validators.required is added or not. Although this is not fool proof it's a good starting point to access the form control inside the custom form element.
constructor(public inj: Injector) {}

ngOnInit() {
  const controlContainer = this.inj.get(ControlContainer);
  this.control = controlContainer!.control!.get(this.formControlName);
  this.required$.next(this.control!.hasValidator(Validators.required));
}

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  OnDestroy,
  AfterViewInit,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  forwardRef,
  Directive,
  inject,
  Injector,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  ControlValueAccessor,
  Validator,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  AbstractControl,
  ValidationErrors,
  Validators,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  NG_VALIDATORS,
  NgControl,
  ControlContainer,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Directive()
export abstract class BaseFormInput<T>
  implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy
{
  @Input() label!: string;
  @Input() formControlName!: string;
  @Output() onChange: EventEmitter<T> = new EventEmitter<T>();

  private changeInternal!: (obj: T) => void;
  private changeSub!: Subscription;
  private disabled$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  private required$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  public input = new FormControl(null);

  control!: AbstractControl<any, any> | null;

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.changeSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  constructor(public inj: Injector) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const controlContainer = this.inj.get(ControlContainer);
    this.control = controlContainer!.control!.get(this.formControlName);
    this.required$.next(this.control!.hasValidator(Validators.required));
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.changeSub = this.input.valueChanges.subscribe((v: any) => {
      if (!this.disabled$.getValue()) {
        this.onChange.emit(v);
        this.changeInternal(v);
      }
    });
  }

  writeValue = (obj: any) => this.input.setValue(obj);

  registerOnChange = (fn: (obj: T) => void) => (this.changeInternal = fn);

  registerOnTouched = (_fn: (obj: any) => void) => {};

  setDisabledState = (isDisabled: boolean) => this.disabled$.next(isDisabled);

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    // THIS LINE HAS WEIRD BEHAVIOR
    // console.log(
    //   control,
    //   control.getError('required'),
    //   control.errors,
    //   control.value
    // );
    return null;
  }

  public get isDisabled$() {
    return this.disabled$.asObservable();
  }

  public get isRequired$() {
    return this.required$.asObservable();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ec-input-text',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `<div class="form-control">
          <label *ngIf="label">
              {{ label }}
              <span *ngIf="isRequired$ | async">*</span>
          </label>
          <input *ngIf="type !== 'textarea'" [type]="type" [formControl]="input" />
          <textarea *ngIf="type === 'textarea'" [formControl]="input" ></textarea>
          <ng-template></ng-template>
      </div>`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputTextComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputTextComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class InputTextComponent extends BaseFormInput<string> {
  @Input() type: 'text' | 'password' | 'email' | 'textarea' = 'text';
  @Input() maxLength!: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule, InputTextComponent],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <ec-input-text label="First name" formControlName="firstName" />
      <ec-input-text label="Last name" formControlName="lastName" />
      <ec-input-text label="E-mail" formControlName="email" type="email" />
      <ec-input-text label="Password" formControlName="password" type="password" />
  </form><br/>
  {{form.errors | json}}
  <br/>
  {{form.controls.firstName.errors | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  public form = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(null, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.maxLength(50),
    ]),
    lastName: new FormControl(null, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.maxLength(50),
    ]),
    email: new FormControl(null, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.maxLength(100),
    ]),
    password: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  });
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

What if I want to add a validator to the control later? Take in example my register-component: when pressing a specific button, I want to add a validator to the formControl, how can I update the required$ observable in the base-component?

@Foreigner you can write a getter method instead of behaviour subject, get hasRequired() {   return this.control?.hasValidator(Validators.required) || false; } will fire on every change detection just like validate method

Thanks! I was also struggling on how to get the original formControl outside the validate method, and your answer helped me!

The issue arises because you’re trying to access properties of an object that are not yet initialized when your method is called.
The errors field that’s causing the issue is populated within your validate method, so it won’t be immediately available when you try to access it. As a result, attempting to read this property directly within validate leads to the problem.
One solution is to use setTimeout to delay your console log. By doing this, you allow validate to finish executing and for all internal fields to be updated. When the timeout expires, your console log will execute with the updated data, allowing you to safely access the errors property. This should resolve the issue.
